# How do i fix the current error I am getting?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe22X.png)I am getting an error in my code for line 6 & 7 & 13 could someone explain to me how to fix it?
It is saying “relocation to ‘displayword’ invalid without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO
It is an entire code to play the game hangman on assembly.

[enter image description here]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFFID.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrQ5N.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Ph2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJhgD.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text.

Comment: *Which* assembly language is this?

Comment: @ScottHunter: LNK2017 is pretty specific. ; I'm pretty sure that OP is also using nasm syntax because of `resb`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (posted as text in the question itself). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not to be seen in the image snapshot.

The problem is you have some code that looks like this:

```
   mov rsi, secretword
```

(or perhaps an `lea` instruction; same difference really)

Such instructions have an offset limit of 32 bits maximum.

What you really want to do is emit the following:

```
   lea rsi, [rel secetword]
```

Now it loads with a displacement within 2GB of itself; and that instruction exists. This bit me once. This instruction also does not exist:

```
   lea rsi, [rel secetword + rbx]
```

When I tried it my assembler was dumb and emitted

```
   lea rsi, [secetword + rbx]
```

instead which caused quite the headache tracking down.

There is a 64 bit `mov` instruction

```
   mov rax, qword secretword
```

but I don't know if the Windows build tools can emit the appropriate fixup or not.

Comment: I added my entire code, could you take a look at it

Comment: @Rebeca: Some [] operations with symbols are marked with offset, some aren't. But _why on earth_ do I see Windows linker errors and Linux 32 bit specific system call gate?

Comment: @Rebeca please just copy/paste your code into the question and on the line before your code put `\`\`\`asm` (those are back-ticks) and on the line after your code put `\`\`\`` to format your code as fixed-text with assemply syntax highlight. For normal text, (no highlight), just omit the `asm` part of the top line. Back-tick is top-left on keyboard on same key as `'~'` (under ESC) on most keyboards.